# How to display only UIview IOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Hi in storyboard i have added a new view controller object inside the view controller i have a small registration from with only two fields example like name and phone number. In that when user open the application i want display only the newly added UIview.

But the problem is uiview is showing with the storyboard please tell me how to display only the uiview. Is that possible to do ? possible means please tell how to make it done. I'm navigating the view from my app-delegate.

App delegate code.

```
      - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
       {    
          UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
          buttonpoliticalViewController *ringingVC = [mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Upcv"];
          [self.window setRootViewController: ringingVC];
          return YES;
        }
```

In above code i have used the storyboard id to view the view controller please tell how to display only uiview.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you add that login view to storyboard and make it initial view controller?

Comment: @DILi i want to show only once like popup thats all pls tell me how to make it

Comment: If u want to have pop displayed only once. you call that popup in ViewDidLoad of initialViewController and use NSUserDefaults to make sure that according to condition its displayed only once.

Comment: For showing UI you have to either you storyboard or xib file. If you don't want storyboard you can go with a xib file, showing the necessary info u needed.